# basic string concatenation syntax confirmation

Tags: basic

I'm new to basic.

Does the following line mean the string `":PULS:WIDT1 "` concatenates with a string variable named `Te`?

```
":PULS:WIDT1 "&VAL$(Te);
```

Comment: Are you sure that’s the full line? Also, do you know where this BASIC code was supposed to run? I.e., what version of BASIC and/or what computer it would run on? I don’t think it will do anything in most BASICs if that’s the full line.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the following line mean the string `":PULS:WIDT1 "` concatenates with a string variable named `Te`?

The line is incomplete. Even if this were an accepted syntax and concatenation somehow took place, where would the result go?

The ampersand character (&) is indeed a string concatenation operator in BASIC, but so is the plus character (+). Not every BASIC allows both, but most will allow at least one.

Inserted in a syntactically correct statement, your expression
`":PULS:WIDT1 "&VAL$(Te)`
would concatenate the `":PULS:WIDT1 "` string litteral with the contents of an element of the string array *VAL$()* indexed by the numerical *Te* variable.

Although `VAL` happens to be the name of a built-in function, many BASICs don't mind that you name one or more user variables the same as a keyword.